# Hibernate getCurrentSession logs (P6SPY) multiple connections?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a doubt, using getCurrentSession of a sessionFactory, it generates many connections to the database.

[P6Spy logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDRm6.png)

when it reaches about 400 the application crashes:

[Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuBEQ.png)

A typical method of a query by hibernate:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

try {
        Session s = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = s.createQuery("from x where c.numFactura = :numFactura");
        query.setParameter("numFactura", numFactura);
        return query.uniqueResult();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
```

I really don't know, if these events are connected, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem wasn't there, I had a problem with the Jasper Reports DB Conection, fixed by autoclosing conection on timeout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).